# Exit swiper container after last slid

Tags: jquery, mobile, swipe, swiper.js

```js
var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
    direction: "vertical",
    pagination: {
      el: ".swiper-pagination",
      clickable: true,
    },
    mousewheelReleaseOnEdges: true
});
```

```css
#main{ width: 100%; height: 300vh; }
.swiper-container{ width: 100%; height: 300vh;}
.swiper-slide{ width: 100%; height: 100vh;}
.swiper-slide:nth-child(1){ background-color: red; }
.swiper-slide:nth-child(2){ background-color: blue; }
.swiper-slide:nth-child(3){ background-color: green; }

#contents{ width: 100%; height: 500px; background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<body>    
   <div id="main">
       <div class="swiper-container mySwiper">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="contents">
        blah blah blah
    </div>
</body>
```

```
 <body>    
   <div id="main">
       <div class="swiper-container mySwiper">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="contents">
        blah blah blah
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
    direction: "vertical",
    pagination: {
      el: ".swiper-pagination",
      clickable: true,
    },
    mousewheelReleaseOnEdges: true
});
</script>


 <style>
        #main{ width: 100%; height: 300vh; }
        .swiper-container{ width: 100%; height: 300vh;}
        .swiper-slide{ width: 100%; height: 100vh;}
        .swiper-slide:nth-child(1){ background-color: red; }
        .swiper-slide:nth-child(2){ background-color: blue; }
        .swiper-slide:nth-child(3){ background-color: green; }
        
        #contents{ width: 100%; height: 500px; background-color: yellow; }
        
    </style>
```

Here is my code. I want to make 3 slides with a height of 100vh, and if I swipe up again on the last slide, I want to come out of the swiper-container and show under contentst.

I've tried some mouse wheel properties and it's possible to get out of the swipe-container using both the swipe and the mouse wheel in the browser. However, when using the only swipe feature on mobile, the screen doens't goes down when swipe up on the last slide. It just stay at swiper-container. please help me.